# asp.net mvc2???? when to use models, controllers, view, script?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

when i create a class or new item? how do i know where or in which directory should i create the class??? i mean how do i know this class has to be created under models or controllers or views or scripts????

Comment: Please read RTFM first. http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/11/13/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-1.aspx

Comment: Multiple question marks do *not* make people more eager to answer.

Comment: I don't know, one more question mark and maybe I wouldn't have vote to close. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you start going through the tutorials on the official Microsoft [MVC](http://asp.net/mvc) site.